# Why is my updated “manifest.json” not being reflected in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

Using `about:debugging#addons` I am loading my own add-on. Additive based on [WEE](https://webextensions-experiments.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html).

I'm forced to change in `manifest.json` `applications > gecko > id` and `version` after each change in code.

When I install in `about: addons`>`Install add-on from file` is the same.

What is Firefox managed. I do not know why Firefox works like this.
It is extremely troublesome.

Is it possible to tame Firefox and its cache? That the addon will load normally, along with your own WEE API?

Comment: It makes sense to me that every version needs it's own version number. You should always do this with everything. Not just FF extensions.

Comment: @HackSlash I fixed the link.  
But you also need to change the extension id. This is definitely not ok.  
Besides, in about: debugging # addons is used for testing rather than releasing a new version!

Comment: What if you loaded two versions of the same extension and they had the same ID? How would FF tell them apart? Every object needs it's own ID. Each version is a new object that could be loaded.

Comment: @HackSlash Whaaat?  
I do not need to load two versions of the same extension at once.  
Why are you writing? You troll.

Comment: RTFM. I'm not trolling. You can have multiple profiles with different versions of the same Extension. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Multiple_profiles

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Firefox 48: If you omit the ID, it will generate one automatically. As explained here in [the official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/WebExtensions_and_the_Add-on_ID):

> Starting in Firefox 48, if your manifest.json does not contain an ID then the extension will be assigned a randomly-generated temporary ID when you install it in Firefox through about:debugging. If you then reload the extension using the "Reload" button, the same ID will be used. If you then restart Firefox and load the add-on again, it will get a new ID.

You do still need to have a unique version number for every version. This is just best practice.